# `%': can't convert Spreadsheet::Column into Integer (TypeError)

Tags: ruby, excel, rubygems, ruby-2.0

I receive the following error while using Ruby 2.0 with the Spreadsheet Gem:

`%': can't convert Spreadsheet::Column into Integer (TypeError)`

I am using the [spreadsheet guide](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/blob/master/GUIDE.md)  for the spreadsheet gem.

```
require 'spreadsheet'

importing = Spreadsheet.open 'file.xls'
book = importing.worksheet 'Sheet1'

book.each do |x, y|
  x = book.column(1)
  y = book.column(2)

  puts x
  puts y
end
```

I am expecting an output like this since that is what I have in the spreadsheet:

```
x    y
32  4
402 6
733 4
1   30
2   3128
2   4
1   1
6   2
10  63
90  333
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `each` method iterates over each row in the spreadsheet. You can then access each value in the row using `[]`s. [This part of the guide is relevant.](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/blob/master/GUIDE.md#reading-is-easy)

Try something like this for your use case:

```
require 'spreadsheet'

importing = Spreadsheet.open 'file.xls'
book = importing.worksheet 'Sheet1'

book.each do |row|
  puts "%-4s%-4s" % row
end
```

`%-4s` means insert a left-justified String with a min-width of 4 spaces. The first two elements in `row` will be substituted in because we have two `%` arguments in the string.

Comment: Where can i find Ruby documentation for string formatting like you specified?

Comment: @Beast_Code The documentation for the format specifiers is at [`Kernel::sprintf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf)

Comment: And lots of languages (Python, Java, C, etc.) use similar format codes, so it's a real helpful thing to be familiar with!